# Decision tree- delete from a specific node

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I have a decision tree that includes node and answer that leads us to another nodes. Answers begin with ":" and nodes are the rest.

[image]

I have to do a function that delete a subtree from a specific node. For example If I want to delete node "brand?", I want that after that the tree will print from `car-color?` to `blue-is-beautiful`

I don't success doing this deletion in the right way because I think I have to delete also the answer `red` and don't know how to do that.

```
class Answer
{
public:
    string ans;
    Node* son;
    Answer(string s, Node* p) { ans = s; son = p; }
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(string v) { isLeaf = true;  value = v; }
    list<Answer*> answersList;
    string value;
    bool isLeaf;
};
void Tree::del(Node* t)
{
    if (t->isLeaf)
        return;
    for (list<Answer*>::iterator it = t->answersList.begin(); it != t->answersList.end(); it++)
    {
        del((*it)->son);
            delete((*it));
            *it = NULL;
    }
    if (t)
    {
        delete t;
        t = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have a problem in your structure. (I haven't identified the specific problem, mind you, hence no 'answer'). This looks to me like a job for a two linked lists. Each node has two extra members, one that points at 'the next item' and another one pointing at 'the children'.

Then, to delete a tree branch, all you need to do is to call 'delete' on the item you want deleted and, in the destructor, you call 'delete' on each child, which, in turn, calls delete on its children, etc. You get the idea.

Why do you need an extra class for 'Answer', when all you need are Nodes?

Comment: Also, don't set `*it` to NULL, but much rather use `it = t->answersList.remove(it);`. Otherwise the item will remain in your list.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium this is a homework and the structure is given. All I have to do is complete functions. I can't change the structure. All the rest of functions is working well, so the problem are in the 2 functions that I send code. Moreover I can't write something like that `it = t->answersList.remove(it);` I can't compile

Comment: @RefugnicEternium `remove` return void and I can't assign to `it`

Comment: My bad. It's not `remove`, it's `erase`. `remove` takes a value to scan for, `erase` removes the given parameter from the list. Also, is there a particular reason, why you are not deleting leaf objects from memory? This looks like a memory leak to me.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I try with erase but this don't fix the code. Can you explain me where I have a memory leak and show me how can I correct code

Comment: In your 'del' function you abort the deletion upon reaching a Leaf object. This means, that the leaf object will not get its answers or itself deallocated. Also, why do you differ between 'leaf object' and 'intermediate object' at all?

Comment: I differ between leaf objet and intermediate object in order to stop recursion I think. But it's not the right way

Comment: I have actually tried to reach out to you on the SO chat to discuss this matter more directly, however you've failed to respond thus far. As for 'stopping recursion', I'm afraid I am missing a tidbit of information there: The structure of the `Tree` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now having understood the problems (highly restrictive requirements and what is causing your code to fail), I now have an answer for you.

The issue is, that you need to remove the node you've deleted from the collection it is stored in.
For this purpose, you need to use an alternate version of your search to detect, which child has the value you are looking for.

Due to the requirement of 'not adding any additional functions', there are two ways to go about this.

One is to employ recursion using an anonymous function, the other is 'check the child prior to diving into it'.

The following code fragment uses a DIY-Lambda-Functor, which employs the recursion method.

```
void Tree::deletefromNode(string val)
{
    bool didFindValue = false;
    std::function<bool (Node *, const string &)> functor;

    class Functor
    {
        public:
            Functor(Tree *owner, bool &didFindValue) : owner(owner), didFindValue(didFindValue)
            {
            }

            bool deleteFromNode(Node *node, const string &value)
            {
                bool foundMatch = false;
                if (node)
                {
                    foundMatch = (node->value == value);

                    if (!foundMatch)
                    {
                        for (list<Answer*>::iterator it = node->answersList.begin(); it != node->answersList.end();)
                        {
                            Node *childNode = (*it)->son;
                            if (deleteFromNode(childNode, value))
                            {
                                owner->del(childNode);
                                it = node->answersList.erase(it);
                                didFindValue = true;
                            }
                            else
                                it++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return foundMatch;
            }

        private:
            Tree *owner;
            bool &didFindValue;
    };

    Functor(this, didFindValue).deleteFromNode(root, val);
    if (didFindValue)
        cout << "Value not found" << endl;
}
```